# I installed MariaDB and it messed up Mysql and I can't uninstall either

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb, clipbucket

So, I've been messing around with Ubuntu lately and I've been running some Virtual hosts and a Terraria server. I decided to install Clipbucket on one of my Virtual servers and I found this guide: https://www.unixmen.com/install-clipbucket-ubuntu-15-10/.

I installed MariaDB, as the guide said, not thinking it would mess with my MySQL. My virtual hosts can't connect to MySQL, I can't run 'mysql -u root -p' because I get the error '
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' after installing MariaDB

I tried to remove MariaDB but it gives this error:

Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   Package 'mariadb-server' is not installed, so not removed
   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or 
   specify a solution).

I decided to run apt --fix-broken install and I get this:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 92893 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1_amd64.deb 
...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-
5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, I'd like to keep my databases but I don't need really need them, I just don't want to re-make them. I've been trying to figure out what to do for a while and I'm just getting really annoyed ;/

EDIT: I couldn't really do anything including apt-get install because it would tell me that it needed the mysql-5.7 for mysql-server and it would fail. I just ended up re-formatting and obviously everything is working fine, and no, my databases did not work so I will have to re-do those as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. I used

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
```

to get rid of the bad MySQL install. But there were apparently still some mariadb packages that were preventing MySQL from installing. Check using

```
dpkg -l | grep '\(maria\|mysql\)'
```

At this point there should be no MySQL packages, but there should be a few mariadb ones.
After confirming the presence of these conflicting packages I removed them using

```
sudo apt-get purge mariadb*
```

I was then able to successfully reinstall MySQL.

Comment: I really wish that I'd have known this at the time. Unfortunately, I was forced to reset my VPS and lost all my databases. Thanks anyways.

Comment: That sucks. I just had a hunch that the MariaDB install was the culprit, as it’s a fork of mysql.

Comment: I did have to remove manually /etc/mysql. After this re-running this command sequence allowed my to successfully re-install mySql.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal type:
`sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a` or
 `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: typing in sudo apt-get install -f does the same thing as apt --fix-broken install. It shows the exact same error. sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a says that --reconfigure is an unknown option.

Comment: Try these 

#sudo apt-get clean
#sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-broken

Comment: or sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: None of that seemed to help. It still displayed errors about MySQL. It seems I cannot even install other packages using sudo apt-get install anymore because of this mysql thing. It says:  mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). As I stated before using apt --fix-broken install does pretty much nothing.

Comment: then Try: sudo apt-get purge mysql-server and then sudo apt-get install mysql-server.It will take a while

Comment: I had done that before and it seemed to work but when I installed it again, it asked me for the password and failed. Anyway, I no longer need help as stated in my edit but thanks anyways.

Comment: It seems you are running an old version of mysql .Just install then reinstall.Your version of mysql-server it is not compatible with mariadb thus creating an error .Purge then reinstall as i mentioned in the above comment.It should work.

Comment: @allways use sudo when uninstalling and installing software or su(log in as root ,super user privileges but sudo is safer

Answer (score 0):

You can completely uninstall **mysql / mariadb** as follow:

```
apt-get purge mariadb-server mariadb-* mysql-*
```

> REMEMBER: **purge** is like saying [ uninstall and remove the config files too ]